# How would you set a custom command to any string in an array?

Tags: discord.js

I've been making a Discord bot, and instead of using a ton of OR operators in my code for each string. I would just like to make an array and have an if statement without five hundred OR operators

This is what I have tried beforehand which didn't work.

```
if (cmd === orb_image_keywords.splice(0,3){
  message.channel.send("orb!", {files: ["https://i.imgur.com/cOCYdAu.png"]});
  console.log("Message was sent")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.includes()` function to check for a specific item inside an array. For example :

```
["a", "b", "c"].includes("a")
> true

["a", "b", "c"].includes("d")
> false
```

Having a second glance at your code, you are accessing `orb_image_keywords[0,1,2]`, but looking at my following example

```
["a", "b", "c"][0, 1, 2]
> "c"
```

you are only retrieving the final item in the retrieval list, which i'm sure is not what you are looking for. If you know the start and end index, you could do `array.slice(start, end)` to get what you want. Note that end is exclusive, and not inclusive, so you will get everything on the left hand side of the end argument

```
["a", "b", "c"].slice(0, 3)
> (3) ["a", "b", "c"]

["a", "b", "c"].slice(0, 2)
> (2) ["a", "b"]
```

Comment: This did not work for what I needed. I don't know why, as there was no error message. I'm very confused. For some reason, the SPLICE argument doesn't work with IF statements, or they don't work with command-related IF statements, one of the two.

Comment: You want `orb_image_keywords.splice(0, 3).includes(cmd)`